# How can I filter an iterator when the predicate returns a Result<bool, _>?

Tags: rust

I would like the iterator to be filtered, but my predicate has the possibility of failing. When the predicate fails, I'd like to fail the entire function. In this example, I'd like `work` to return the `Result` generated by `maybe`:

```
fn maybe(v: u32) -> Result<bool, u8> {
    match v % 3 {
        0 => Ok(true),
        1 => Ok(false),
        2 => Err(42),
    }
}

fn work() -> Result<Vec<u32>, u8> {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().filter(|&&x| maybe(x)).collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", work())
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:45
   |
10 |         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().filter(|&&x| maybe(x)).collect()
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^ expected bool, found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `bool`
              found type `std::result::Result<bool, u8>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, u8>: std::iter::FromIterator<&u32>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:55
   |
10 |         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().filter(|&&x| maybe(x)).collect()
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, u8>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&u32`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&u32>` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u32>, u8>`
```

Comment: I think  in your case would be better to just use a loop: `try!(maybe(x))` and push the values into a mutable `Vec<u32>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn the `Result<bool, u8>` into an `Option<Result<u32, u8>>`, that is, pull the `bool` out to an `Option` and put the value inside, and use `filter_map`:

```
fn maybe(v: u32) -> Result<bool, u8> {
    match v % 3 {
        0 => Ok(true),
        1 => Ok(false),
        _ => Err(42),
    }
}

fn work() -> Result<Vec<u32>, u8> {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|&x| match maybe(x) {
            Ok(true) => Some(Ok(x)),
            Ok(false) => None,
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", work())
}
```

[playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=fn%20maybe%28v%3A%20u32%29%20-%3E%20Result%3Cbool%2C%20u8%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20v%20%25%203%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%20%3D%3E%20Ok%28true%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%20%3D%3E%20Ok%28false%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20Err%2842%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20work%28%29%20-%3E%20Result%3CVec%3Cu32%3E%2C%20u8%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D.iter%28%29.filter_map%28%7C%26x%7C%20match%20maybe%28x%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok%28true%29%20%3D%3E%20Some%28Ok%28x%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok%28false%29%20%3D%3E%20None%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err%28e%29%20%3D%3E%20Some%28Err%28e%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29.collect%28%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20work%28%29%29%0A%7D)